# Electrolysis of a calcium salt in polar aprotic solvent

Tags: electrochemistry, electrolysis, solvents, elements

If i found a calcium salt that is soluble in acetone or ethyl acetate, which are polar aprotic solvents, and attempted electrolysis, what would happen? Since polar aprotic solvents are used in metal-air batteries I don't think there would be a reaction between the newly formed metal and solvent. At the same time, no one uses such method industrially. Maybe it's just inefficient, or maybe it doesn't work?

Comment: https://www.nature.com/articles/183816a0

Comment: Hmm, there was a very similar q. recently... Why you guys think about solvents that can be reduced?